# Highlight parent menu item on subpage (with ngRoute)

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I'm building a mobile app with AngularJs that uses a Bottom Navigation Bar.

The navigation structure looks basically like this:

- teams

  - teamDetail

    - gameDetail
- groups

  - teamDetail

    - gameDetail

So teamDetail/gameDetail can have the parent page "teams" or "groups". If user is on page groups, then the groups item is highlighted. If user clicks on teamDetail and then gameDetail, then still groups item should be highlighted.

If user is on page "teams" and clicks on teamDetail and then gameDetail the teams item should be highlighted.

So basically I have a detail page that can be in different parent pages and I would like to highlight the specific parent page from where the user has navigated.

index.html

```
<a ng-class="{active: highlightTab('teams')}">Teams</a>
<a ng-class="{active: highlightTab('groups')}">Groups</a>
```

controller.js

```
function highlightTab(tab) {
    return $route.current.activeTab == tab;
}
```

app.js

```
.when('/teams',
    {
      templateUrl: 'app/partials/teams.html',
      title: 'All teams',
      activeTab: 'teams',
    })
.when('/groups',
    {
      templateUrl: 'app/partials/groups.html',
      title: 'Groups',
      activeTab: 'groups',
    })
.when('/teamDetail',
    {
      templateUrl: 'app/partials/teamDetail.html',
      title: 'Team detail',
      activeTab: '???', // this is depending on user navigation 
    })
.when('/gameDetail',
    {
      templateUrl: 'app/partials/gameDetail.html',
      title: 'Game detail',
      activeTab: '???', // this is depending on user navigation
    })
```

**NOTE:** I would really like to achive this without using angular ui-router.

Comment: How is what you want to do different that [AngularJS ngRoute $route Service API Reference - Example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example)?

Comment: It's different because here, teamDetail can be the child page of either groups or teams. In the example there is only one child page with only one parent page.

Additionally, I need to know for gameDetail what is the parent-parent-page (either groups or teams)